# Catch keyboard shortcuts in iOS simulator for debugging - like React Native CMD + R

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, react-native

Can anyone point me to some information on how to catch keyboard shortcuts in the iOS simulator and hook them up to debug methods?

After playing with React Native on iOS, I found the CMD+R keyboard shortcut extremely useful and wanted to integrate similar features in my other apps.

For those that don't know, [react-native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) uses a javascript interpreter to write applications, and devs can simply hit CMD+R in the iOS simulator to trigger a reload of the javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple. In your view-controller, override the `keyCommands` method (which is a `UIResponder` method you can override) and return an array of the commands you'd like to handle. Here's an example that handles ⌘+w:

```
- (NSArray<UIKeyCommand *>*)keyCommands
{
    return @[[UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:@"w" modifierFlags:UIKeyModifierCommand action:@selector(onKeyboardModifier:)]];
}

- (void)onKeyboardModifier:(UIKeyCommand *)keyCommand
{
    NSLog(@"key modifier triggered: %@", keyCommand.input);
}
```